# How to transfer data from sql anywhere 17 to sql anywhere 9?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sqlanywhere

I need to transfer data from sql anywhere 17 to sql anywhere 9
Coyld you tell me, how can I transfer data? What should I do?
I have a *.db file with data for sql anywhere 17. I need to convert/transfer data to sql anywhere 9
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Sybase Central -> Tools -> Sql Anywhere -> Unload Database. This will open a unload wizard.

[image: Go to Sybase Central -> Tools -> Sql Anywhere -> Unload Database. This will open a unload wizard.]

There you will have different options to unload your database file to reloadable sql file or directly to another database.
[image: There you will have different options to unload your database file to reloadable sql file or directly to another database.]